# Getting Help From Adviser's Friend

Tags: advisor, preprint

My MSc thesis is about a subject that my adviser isn't completely familiar with. In my work, I found some new result. He said it is better to show the results to one of his friend that has expertise and is more familiar with this subject.

I suggested to first publish a pre-print in arXive, before showing result to others, but he objected I should just publish a completed work. However, I don't know if I can trust his friend or not.

What can I do?

Comment: Trust this friend to or not to do what, exactly? Are you worried that this friend of your advisor will steal your work?

Comment: If you don't trust your adviser, or someone he recommends, then you probably shouldn't be working with him.

Comment: I'd only be worried if his was friend was this Nigerian prince he met online.

Comment: @CliffAB yeah be very careful about all these Nigerian princes trying to steal your math preprints.

Comment: @BillBarth maybe , or similar thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have two way of going through this.

First, trust by default. I am not sure what you are afraid of in the first place, maybe that this friend steals your work? Your advisor could do that himself if he wanted to, and it does not seems credible he would refer you to someone in the sole purpose of stealing your job. 
Also, this friends is presumably another academic and stealing the job of a MSc student seems moot, since they can just wait you to finish it and then reference to your work for their research if they want it.

The second option is to ignore that request. But you won't get any review of your work and would have to put on the show and review the work yourself to make it convincing. Hopefully your advisor won't ask his friend about it.